# Having trouble with inserting date in to database

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I’m having trouble inserting into a `MySQL` data table, using `C#` & `ODBC` 5.1. The insert fails when it attempts to write into a `DateTime` field. `MySQL` says that the `DateTime` value is not in the correct format. It says that the value I’m inserting is:

```
13-07-2012 13:46:21.000031000.
```

As you can see, there’s a bunch of decimal digits for the seconds. I can’t work out why these are being added. If I insert a row manually (e.g. using MySQL Workbench), and supply a value like:

```
13-07-2012 13:46:21
```

`MySQL` doesn’t seem to add a decimal & the insert completes successfully. As far as I can see, the `DateTime` from `C#` to the `ODBC` Parameter doesn’t contain these decimals, so it seems that something in `MySQL` at some point is adding them!

Comment: i think you'll find its the C# datetime format

Comment: Correct format for datetimes in MySQL is `'2012-07-13 13:46:21'`

Comment: Hi Jaitsu. Thanks for that. So, you are saying that C# is passing through "13-07-2012 13:46:21.000031000"? The same code works completely fine on several other machines. It is just problematic on this computer, for some reason, even though the setup on .net & mysql are (as far as I know) exactly the same.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Hi, ypercube thanks for your reply,The error message is System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.63-community]Incorrect datetime value: '2012-07-13 15:05:08.499000000' for column 'CreationDate' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

I would use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE function to convert the C# formatted date string to one that MySQL can use:

```
STR_TO_DATE("13-07-2012 13:46", "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i")
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Hi, ypercube thanks for your  reply,The error message is System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.63-community]Incorrect datetime value: '2012-07-13 15:05:08.499000000' for column 'CreationDate' at row 1